# get a getter method from field name to avoid if-else

Tags: java, if-statement, comparator, java-11

I have this code, which obviously doesn't look nice - it seems all the if-else can somehow be avoided.

```java
if(sortBy.equals("firstName"))
 personList.sort(Comparator.comparing(Person::getFirstName));
else if(sortBy.equals("lastName")) 
 personList.sort(Comparator.comparing(Person::getLastName));
else if(sortBy.equals("age")) 
 personList.sort(Comparator.comparing(Person::getAge));
else if(sortBy.equals("city")) 
 personList.sort(Comparator.comparing(Person::getCity));
else if(sortBy.equals("state")) 
 personList.sort(Comparator.comparing(Person::getState));
else if(sortBy.equals("zipCode")) 
 personList.sort(Comparator.comparing(Person::getZipCode));
```

the function takes `sortBy`, which is the name of one of the attributes of a `Person`, and applies a sorting to a `personList` based on that field. How can I avoid the if-else and write a better looking, possibily one line code?

Currently I have found that I can use a HashMap to create a mapping between a field name and a corresponding comparator.

```java
map.put("age", Comparator.comparing(Person::getAge));
map.put("firstName", Comparator.comparing(Person::getFirstName))
...
```

And use `personList.sort(map.get(sortBy))`.

But still felt like it can further be improved without an extra step, to the point where it follows the open-closed principle, and adding a new field to `Person` would not need us to modify the code. I'm looking for something like

```
personList.sort(Comparator.comparing(Person::getterOfField(sortBy)))
```

**UPDATE-1**

For now, I decided to stick with using a `Map<String, Function<Person, Comparable<?>>` and I do not like to consider reflection based solutions. But still searching if I can find a similar way as [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-pagination-sorting) one where sort is a parameter.

**UPDATE-2**

I think a one-liner is not a good solution, cuz you wouldn't get a compile time error if one of the fields does not implement Comparator.

Comment: Reflection, perhaps. But reflection has its own issues. Or move the name match into a method in the class. Note that switch/case works on strings.

Comment: A `Map<String, Function<Person, Comparable<?>>` or similar?

Comment: An explicitly populated map of strings to comparators like you already have, is preferable. After all, you have to provide a UI with human readable labels, perhaps translated into different languages. So, adding a new sort option doesn't come for free when you add a new property anyway. The other direction is even more problematic: when the string comes from an external source, like web request or config file, having an automatism that allows accessing arbitrary members by string becomes a stability/security problem. As said, a map specifying explicitly supported properties is preferable.

Comment: @OleV.V. Thank you. that's actually better than using a comparator as the value of the map. I will use that one.

Answer (score 2):

In general java doesn't want you to work with it this way<sup>1</sup>; it is not a structurally typed language, and unlike e.g. javascript or python, objects aren't "hashmaps of strings to thingies".

Also, your request more fundamentally doesn't add up: You can't *just* go from "field name" to "sort on that": What if the field's type isn't inherently sortable (is not a subtype of `Comparator<Self>`?)

What if there is a column in whatever view we're talking about / config file that is 'generated'? Imagine you have a field `LocalDate birthDate;` but you have a column 'birth month'<sup>2</sup>. You can sort on birth month, no problem. However, given that it's a 'generated value' (not backed directly by a field, instead, derived from a calculation based on field(s)), you can't just sort on this. You can't even sort on the backing field (as that would sort by birth year first, not what you want), nor does 'backing field' make sense; what if the virtual column is based on multiple fields?

It is certainly possible that currently you aren't imagining either virtual columns or fields whose type isn't self-sortable and that therefore you want to deposit a rule that for this class, you **close the door** on these two notions until a pretty major refactor, but it goes to show perhaps why "java does not work that way" is in fact somewhat 'good' (closely meshes with real life concerns), and why your example isn't as boilerplatey as you may have initially thought: No, it is **not**, in fact, inevitable. Specifically, you seem to want:

- There is an exact 1-to-1 match between 'column sort keys' and field names.
- The strategy to deliver on the request to sort on a given column sort key is always the same: Take the column sort key. Find the field (it has the same name); now find its getter. Create a comparator based on comparing get calls; this getter returns a type that has a natural sorting order guaranteed.

Which are 2 non-obvious preconditions that seem to have gotten a bit lost. At any rate, a statement like:

```
if(sortBy.equals("firstName"))
 personList.sort(Comparator.comparing(Person::getFirstName));
```

*encodes* these 2 non-obvious properties, and trivially, therefore means it is also possible to add virtual columns as well as sort keys that work differently (for example, sorts on birth month, or, sorts on some explicit comparator you write for this purpose. Or even sorts case insensitively; strings by default do not do that, you'd have to sort by `String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_COMPARATOR` instead.

It strikes me as a rather badly written app if a change request comes in with: "Hey, could you make the sort option that sorts on patient name be case insensitive?" and you go: "Hooo boy that'll be a personweek+ of refactoring work!", no?

But, if you insist, you have 2 broad options:

### Reflection

Reflection lets you write code that programatically gets a list of field names, method names, and can also be used to programatically call them. You can fetch a list of method names and filter out everything except:

- instance methods
- with no arguments
- whose name starts with `get`

And do a simple-ish get-prefix-to-sort-key conversion (basically, `.substring(3)` to lop off the `get`, then lowercase the first character, though note that the rules for getter to field name get contradictory if the first 'word' of the field is a single letter, such as `getXAxis`, where half of the beanspec documents say the field name is definitely `XAxis`, as `xAxis` would have become `getxAxis`, and the other half say it is ambiguous and could mean the field name is `XAxis` or `xAxis`).

It looks something like this:

```
// intentionally raw type!
Map comparators = new HashMap();
for (Method m : Person.class.getMethods()) {
  if (Modifiers.isStatic(m.getModifiers()) continue;
  if (m.getParameterCount() != 0) continue;
  String n = m.getName();
  if (!n.startsWith("get") || n.length() < 4) continue;
  n = Character.toLowerCase(n.charAt(3)) + n.substring(4);
  comparators.put(n, (a, b) -> {
    Object aa = m.invoke(a);
    Object bb = m.invoke(b);
    return ((Comparable) aa).compareTo(bb);
  });
}
MyClass.COMPARATORS = (Map<String, Comparator<?>>) Collections.unmodifiableMap(comparators);
```

Note how this causes a boatload of errors because you just chucked type checking out the window - there is no actual way to ensure that any given getter type actually *is* an appropriate Comparable. The warnings are correct and you have to ignore them, no fixing that, if you go by this route.

You also get a ton of checked exceptions issues that you'll have to deal with by catching them and rethrowing something appropriate; possibly `RuntimeException` or similar if you want to disregard the need to deal with them by callers (some RuntimeException is appropriate if you consider any attempt to add a field of a type that isn't naturally comparable 'a bug').

### Annotation Processors

This is a lot more complicated: You can stick annotations on a method, and then have an annotation processor that sees these and *generates* a source file that does what you want. This is more flexible and more 'compile time checked', in that you can e.g. check that things are of an appropriate type, or add support for mentioning a class in the annotation that is an implementation of `Comparable<T>`, T being compatible with the type of the field you so annotate. You can also annotate methods themselves (e.g. a `public Month getBirthMonth()` method). I suggest you search the web for an annotation processor tutorial, it'd be a bit much to stuff an example in an SO answer. Expect to spend a few days learning and writing it, it won't be trivial.

[1] This is a largely objective statement. Falsifiable elements: There are no field-based 'lambda accessors'; no `foo::fieldName` support. Java does not support structural typing and there is no way to refer to things in the language by name alone, only by fully qualified name (you can let the compiler infer things, but the compiler always translates what you write to a fully "named" (package name, type name that the thing you are referring to is in, and finally the name of the method or field) and then sticks *that* in the class file).

[2] At least in the Netherlands it is somewhat common to split patient populations up by birth month (as a convenient way to split a population into 12 roughly equally sized, mostly arbitrary chunks) e.g. for inviting them in for a checkup or a flu shot or whatnot.

Comment: `(a, b) -> ((Comparator) a).compareTo(b)` is very strange. You surely meant `Comparable` here, but then the comparator would be identical to `Comparator.naturalOrder()`. There is no point in creating a map from names to identical comparators. A comparator actually using `Method m` to read the property to compare would make more sense, but is significantly more elaborated that this one-liner.

Comment: first of thank you for taking your time to explain in detail.

Comment: @Holger fair enough. I shall update the answer; not only is my code [A] wrong and [B] needlessly complicated, I also [C] didn't explain it. A major edit is required in any case, might as well just go for the most obvious (naturalOrder) option.

Comment: @Holger Actually, correction - I want natural order but not of the object itself, but of whatever is returned when invoking the getter, which I don't know how to write offhand without some particularly egregious casting-to-raw-types, so I thought I'd hop into a basic lambda to avoid it, but then I promptly forgot to call `m.invoke`. I think I addressed the snippet now. Good eye for seeing that part wasn't up to snuff!

Comment: I’d create one `Function` calling `m.invoke` and then use `Comparator.comparing`. Since the former has the shape of a functional interface calling one method, it would be possible to use either, `LambdaMetaFactory` which would be very efficient but require elaborated code or use `MethodHandleProxies.asInterfaceInstance(…)` which is not as efficient but very simple to write. As said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73516275/73517744?noredirect=1#comment129825641_73516275) I wouldn’t recommend arbitrary reflective calls anyway. Though `record` components would have the right semantics.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the `sortBy` values and the corresponding getters are known at compile, this would be a good place to use a string `switch` statement:

```
Function<Person.String> getter = null;
switch (sortBy) {
    case "firstName":
        getter = Person::getFirstName; break;
    case "lastName":
        getter = Person::getLastName; break;
    ...
}
personList.sort(Comparator.comparing(getter));
```

If you use a recent version of Java (Java 12 and later) you could use a `switch` expression rather than a `switch` statement.

```
Function<Person.String> getter;
getter = switch (sortBy) {
    case "firstName" -> Person::getFirstName; 
    case "lastName" -> Person::getLastName;
    ...
    default -> null;
}
personList.sort(Comparator.comparing(getter));
```

Note: you should do a better job (than my dodgy code) of dealing with the case where the `sortBy` value is not recognized.

Comment: Thank you, Stephen. the switch statement is of course better than the if-else although it still didn't solve the problem. I was expecting to avoid checking for each case. Thanks for the effort.

Comment: It is equivalent to a `Map` that you have prepopulated with name -> getter mappings.  Literally.  Under the hood, a string switch will typically use a prepopulated HashMap

Comment: yes, it's similar. I'm not saying the `Map` solution satisfied me. Your switch statement still didn't avoid the case checking.

Comment: There is no way to avoid it, AFAIK.  Apart from reflection ...

Answer (score 1):

As keshlam suggested, I think using the reflection API is the best fitting answer to your question, but keep in mind that using it in production code is generally discouraged.

Note: if you add a new `Person`-attribute which isn't itself `Comparable`, you'll have to resort to a custom `Comparator` anyway. With that in mind, you might want to keep the `Map<String, Comparator<?>>` solution you already have.

Comment: Thank you for the effort. I am also not looking for reflection based solution. But you are right, the Map solution is better. I'm going with `Map<String, Function<Person, Comparable<?>>` for now.